# Random Sentence Generator / Listbox output

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

I am trying to make a windows form in `C#` that will have four arrays with 5 random words in them.  I will then create a button to generate a random sentence using the words from the array.  Right now I am trying to output the sentences to a list box but I am getting errors. What is the code to output this information to a listbox? Here is my code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Chapter_16_Ex._16._4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGenerator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] article = { "the", "a", "one", "some", "any", };
            string[] noun = { "boy", "girl", "dog", "town", "car", };
            string[] verb = { "drove", "jumped", "ran", "walked", "skipped", };
            string[] preposition = { "to", "from", "over", "under", "on", };

            Random rndarticle = new Random();
            Random rndnoun = new Random();
            Random rndverb = new Random();
            Random rndpreposition = new Random();

            int randomarticle = rndarticle.Next(article.Length);
            int randomnoun = rndnoun.Next(noun.Length);
            int randomverb = rndverb.Next(verb.Length);
            int randompreposition = rndpreposition.Next(preposition.Length);

            listBox1.Items.Add("{0} {1}",article[randomarticle],noun[randomnoun]);


        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors are you seeing?

Comment: We'll basically I can do "listBox1.Items.Add(article[randomarticle]);" and that give me the first word with no errors, however I need to out put a word from each array to complete the sentence and when I try to add the second random word I get "NO Overload for method "Add takes 2 arguments" I am not sure if I need to use placeholders.  I am new to listboxes.

Comment: Note: Do not create those separate randon generators! They will all be the same, since they all are created at the same time, that is with the same timestamp-seed! Create one as a static class variable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Listbox.Items.Add
```

does not take 3 parameters

you will need to use String.Format when you use '{0} {1}' and you want to add values to that

```
listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", article[randomarticle], noun[randomnoun]));
```

or you could also just do it like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(article[randomarticle] + " " + noun[randomnoun]);
```

if i do it like that, it works perfect.

Comment: Thanks man, just another quick question, If I wanted the program to generate 10 sentences instead of just 1, would it be easier to just copy that code 10 times, or is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add **string values** to listbox control. So you should add your sentence like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", article[randomarticle], noun[randomnoun]));
```